# Does there exist a conformal map from the unbounded region outside the disks $\{z:|z-1|\le 1\}\cup \{z:|z+1|\le 1\}$ to the upper half plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

> Does there exist a conformal map from the unbounded region outside the disks  $\{z:|z-1|\le 1\}\cup \{z:|z+1|\le 1\}$ to the upper half plane?

In order to find the conformal map we need to find $f(z)$ which keeps the points in the unbounded region outside the disks  $\{z:|z-1|\le 1\}\cup \{z:|z+1|\le 1\}$ which are in the upper half plane intact but moves the points in the lower 
half plane to upper half plane.

I thought of $f(z)=z^2$ but its not working.

Can I get some hint?

Comment: Let $U$ be the unbounded region outside the disks and $H$ the open upper halfplane. Do you want a conformal map mapping $U$ into $H$ or a *bijective* conformal map?

Comment: @PaulFrost;only a conformal map

Comment: You should make precise what you mean by the unbouded region outside the disks: The complement of the union of these disks  in $\mathbb C$ or in the Riemann sphere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complement of those two disk in the *extended complex plane*
$$
 D = \hat{\Bbb  C} \setminus (\{z:|z-1|\le 1\}\cup \{z:|z+1|\le 1\})
$$
is simply-connected. The Riemann mapping theorem guarantees that there is a bijective conformal mapping from $D$ to the upper half-plane.

If you want an *explicit map* then I would start with $z \mapsto 1/z$, which maps $D$ to the region between two parallel lines. This strip is mapped to $\{ z: 0 < \operatorname{Im}(z) < \pi \}$ with a rotation and translation, and finally to the upper half-plane with the exponential function.

All used functions are conformal and bijective in the domain where they are used, so that the composition is conformal and bijective.

Comment: Do you mind if i ask you to explain a bit more

Comment: @Math_Freak: Which part is unclear?

Comment: how to show that the map is conformal?can you explain how to prove that it indeed maps the region to upper half plane

Comment: @Math_Freak: $1/z$ is a “Möbiustransformation” and maps the two circles to circles or lines. Since $0$ goes to $\infty$, the image of the two circles must be lines. And because the circles interest the real axis at a right angle, the same must be true for the images, which are therefore lines parallel to the y-axis.

Comment: yes but how do you know that it will be mapped to upper half plane

Comment: @Math_Freak: Map the strip to $\{ z: 0 < \operatorname{Im}(z) < \pi \}$. Then see what the exponential function does with this strip.

Comment: oh okay,thanks a lot

Comment: $1/z$ establishes a conformal bijection between the unbounded region outside the disks and the region $G = \{ z \in \mathbb C \mid -1/2 < \text {Re}(z) < 1/2 \} \setminus \{ 0 \}$ which is a punctured strip. There is a conformal bijection between $G$ and a punctured open upper half plane, but not between $G$ and the full open upper half plane. But if you take the complement of the disks in the Riemann sphere, you are right.

Comment: @PaulFrost: That what I meant. I have tried to clarify the answer. Thanks for the feedback.